# Problem with UIImagePickerController swift

Tags: ios, swift

Im working in an application which requires the camera. The way Im opening it is this:

```
let Picker = UIImagePickerController()
Picker.delegate = self
Picker.sourceType = .camera
present(Picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Everything works perfectly, this is the result which I get:

[image]

What I would like to do now is replace that "Cancel" button for a button which let the user select a photo from his photolibrary. I have been reading a lot but I still do not get a solution.

Thank to everyone

Comment: For this, you have to create custom layer on camera and remove camera controls

Comment: Why don't you present user with options to choose from the photo library or camera before opening camera.

Comment: Build a custom `UIImagePickerController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it instead of that

```
    @IBAction func buttonOnClick(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        self.openCamera()
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        self.openGallary()
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    /*If you want work actionsheet on ipad
    then you have to use popoverPresentationController to present the actionsheet,
    otherwise app will crash on iPad */
    switch UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom {
    case .pad:
        alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
        alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds
        alert.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .up
    default:
        break
    }

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func openCamera()
{
    if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera))
    {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        let alert  = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You don't have camera", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func openGallary()
{
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are doing this 2 things:

1. Specifying the content type you are looking for:
   `Picker.mediaTypes = [KUTTypeImage as String, KUTTypeMovie as String]`, for example to select both videos and images.
2. That you added in your **info.plist** the camera permission description **Privacy - Camera Usage Description**

[image: Like this]